# Monogame make objects in class move independently

Tags: c#, block, game-physics, monogame, bounce

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to make 2000 blocks bounce on the screen. I have made it work with one block but when I add more the x and y-axis update on all of them as soon as one of them hit the borders at the edge of the screen. So I want all objects x and y axises to update independently and not move together as they're doing right now. Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project_blob
{
public class Game1 : Game
{
    private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;
    Texture2D pixelTexture;
    List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
    Block block;
    int speed1 = 1;
    int speed2 = -1;
    



    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        
        Random rnd = new Random();
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        block = new Block();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            var block = new Block();
            block.X = rnd.Next(0, 780);
            block.Y = rnd.Next(0, 500);
            block.Color = new Color(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
            blocks.Add(block);
            

        }
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        pixelTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pixel");
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        foreach (Block block in blocks)
        {
            if (block.X < 0) speed2 += 1;
            if (block.X > 770) speed2 += -1;
            if (block.Y > 450) speed1 += -1;
            if (block.Y < 0) speed1 += 1;
            if (speed1 < -1) speed1 = -1;
            if (speed1 > 1) speed1 = 1;
            if (speed2 < -1) speed2 = -1;
            if (speed2 > 1) speed2 = 1;
            block.X += speed2;
            block.Y += speed1;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
        
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        _spriteBatch.Begin();
        foreach (Block block in blocks)
        {
            block.Draw(_spriteBatch, pixelTexture);
        }
        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

and then Block.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Project_blob
 {
 public class Block
{
        public int X { get; set; } = 100;
        public int Y { get; set; } = 100;
        public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.Red;
        public int speed1 = 1;
        public int speed2 = -1;

   
   


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D texture)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(X, Y, 30, 30), Color);
        }
    
}
}
```

Would be thankful if you were to help me in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend putting them in a personal Update() class. They'll need to make use of their local `speed1` and `speed2` variables, and the global `speed1` and `speed2` in the game1.cs should be removed to avoid confusion.

Something like this:

in game1.cs:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        Exit();

    foreach (Block block in blocks)
    {
        block.Update();
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
    
}
```

In Block.cs:

```
public void Update()
{
    if (X < 0) speed2 += 1;
    if (X > 770) speed2 += -1;
    if (Y > 450) speed1 += -1;
    if (Y < 0) speed1 += 1;
    if (speed1 < -1) speed1 = -1;
    if (speed1 > 1) speed1 = 1;
    if (speed2 < -1) speed2 = -1;
    if (speed2 > 1) speed2 = 1;
    X += speed2;
    Y += speed1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have global variables for `speed1` and `speed2` in your game, where I think you're trying to calculate these for each individual block. Just make them local in the loop and reset them each iteration

```
 foreach (Block block in blocks)
 {
    var speed1 = 1;
    var speed2 = -1;
    if (block.X < 0) speed2 += 1;
    if (block.X > 770) speed2 += -1;
    if (block.Y > 450) speed1 += -1;
    if (block.Y < 0) speed1 += 1;
    if (speed1 < -1) speed1 = -1;
    if (speed1 > 1) speed1 = 1;
    if (speed2 < -1) speed2 = -1;
    if (speed2 > 1) speed2 = 1;
    block.X += speed2;
    block.Y += speed1;
 }
```

Comment: This seems to work in them moving independently but they no longer "bounce" when they hit the walls